# How to capture CPU usage of a certain process to output txt file

Tags: linux, file, terminal

I tried to capture CPU usage of a certain process filtered by PID to output file:

```
top -b -n 1 -p {PID} | tail -n 2 | head -n 2 | awk '{print $1, $12, $9}' > out.txt
```

It always gives me the value 0.0%.

I need also to capture the value every second for the entire execution time of a process until I break the capture, because I don't know for how long the process will be active.

Comment: The command should work, if it outputs 0.0 this means that the process really shows no CPU usage - in that moment when you run the command. However, the command can be simplified to this `top -b -n 1 -p {PID}   |  awk 'NR==8{print $1, $12, $9}'`

Comment: for every second? you can use a while loop. `while true; do top -b -n 1 -p {PID} | awk 'NR==8{print $1, $12, $9}'; sleep 1; done > out.txt` press CTRL-C to stop it.

Comment: @hek2mgl cpu usage of a process exists the whole time, I'm paralelly watching it in top

Comment: Run the command in a  loop. Is it always `0.0` while `x.x` in the top that runs in parallel?

Comment: How can I track multiple PIDs ?